# How to update repository Incremental in Nexus3 without the Internet?

Tags: java, maven, nexus3

Hi I deployed a Nexus Repository Manager OSS 3.3.1-01 in local area network which can not connect the center maven repository.
So I also deployed a Nexus on the Internet.
I use a POM file which include all the jar I needed to download all dependencies on the Internet.
Then copy the "sonatype-work" directory to local area network via DVD.
At last I overwrite the original "sonatype-work" directory.

**BUT**,I think this is not a good solution.Beacuse Even if I just need update a very small jar,I need overwrite all "sonatype-work" directory.
**SO**,How to update repository Incremental in Nexus3 without the Internet？

Comment: Why is your intranet Nexus server not able to access the internet? The whole point of having a repository manager on your intranet is so that you could have a central place in your company/environment, which has a place for you to store, retrieve and cache artifacts retrieved from the Internet from. What you're doing lacks any sense. You need to allow access to the Internet to your internal Nexus server (set the proxy settings and so on).

Comment: In theory you can do that manually if you have many resources and many time...but in practice as already mentioned useless...contradicts the whole idea of a repository manager.

Comment: The intranet and the Internet are physically isolated.